# Рекурсивный вывод массива (оператор return), методы java

Tags: java, рекурсия

Есть код вывода массива элементов в стандартном выходном потоке:

```
public class Example
{
    int values[];

    Example (int i)
    {
        values = new int[i];
    }
    void PrintArray (int i)
    {
        if(i==0) return;
        else PrintArray(i-1);

        System.out.println("[" + (i-1) + "] " + values[i-1]);
    }
}


public class Recurtion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Example obj = new Example(10);
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            obj.values[i] = i;
        }

        obj.PrintArray(10);
    }
}
```

Вопрос:

Каким образом программа доходит до строчки? Непосредственно вывод при разворачивании рекурсии.

```
System.out.println("[" + (i-1) + "] " + values[i-1]);
```

Comment: А вы отладчик включите и по шагай пройдитесь - все станет ясно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод PrintArray вызывается с аргументами от 10 до 0.

С аргументом 0 выполняется:

```
if(i==0) return;
```

Далее после вызова:

```
else PrintArray(i-1);
```

Продолжает выполняться последняя инструкция метода:

```
System.out.println("[" + (i-1) + "] " + values[i-1]);
```

И так для всех рекурсивных вызовов.

Comment: Спасибо! Построчно проходил, но все же не до конца понятно почему после i==0 и выполненного return, программа выполняет else  и вывод массива?! Возможно ли еще более подробно разжевать? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: При i==0 происходит выход из метода и возврат к месту его вызова, а там следующая инструкция выполняется. Так вверх до самого первого вызова.

Answer (score 1):

Почитай про стек вызовов станет понятнее как рекурсия работает. Исходя из кода метод не выведет нулевой элемент массива, потому что на нуле стоит возврат из последнего вызова и печать начнется с первого, а не с нулевого элемента массива.

Answer (score 0):

Я что-то вообще завис на этой рекурсии.Не могу понять, как выполняются эти строки.То что, здесь ответили вообще ничего не объяснило, а только запутало.
Массив идет слева направо.Есть число вводное 10

```
if(i==0) return; Оно не равно 0, значит идет дальше.
else PrintArray(i-1);    Здесь разве не (10 - 1) ?
System.out.println("[" + (i-1) + "] ") Здесь значит должно выводится 9
```

Это по логике.Но каким-то неведомым способом, этот метод выдает числа задом наперед.Как из 10 сразу получается 1.
Может кто объяснить ?